# Accessibility Mac Screen Reader Aria-Live React-Redux

Tags: redux, react-router, react-redux, accessibility

I am using react redux to communicate changes in the routes (see http://almerosteyn.com/2017/03/accessible-react-navigation for details on implementation). The issue I'm running into is if I navigate from one route to another through a button click (pressing enter) the screen reader reads about the button details while loading the next page. Once it's loaded though it doesn't read the message in the a11y message.

Is there a way I can force it to read out, ensuring even if its late that it load?

```
  render() {
    const { currentA11yMessage } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="sr-only"
             role="status"
             aria-live="polite"
             aria-atomic="true">
            {currentA11yMessage ? <span>{currentA11yMessage}</span> : ''}
        </div>
    );
   }

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        //We delay the setting and clearing of the accessible route transition
        //text to ensure that the screen readers don't miss it.
        if(nextProps.a11yMessage){
            setTimeout(()=>{this.setState({
                currentA11yMessage: nextProps.a11yMessage
            })}, 50);
            setTimeout(()=>{this.setState({
                currentA11yMessage: ''
            })}, 500)
        }
    }
```